# SQL statement. Return rows if one or more conditions are true

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to create an SQL statement that returns rows if one or more conditions in the WHERE clause are true. The SQL statement u can see below. The problem now is that all conditions must be true. If I replace the AND for OR it will still not work because then the query will not return rows where 2 or 3 conditions are true.
I know I can solve this with a UNION. But this is bad for the performance. Anyone has a better solution?

```
SELECT W*.
FROM WORK W JOIN WORKSHOP WS ON W.ID = WS.WORKID
WHERE W.COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL
  AND (W.COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL AND W.COLUMN2 != -1)
  AND WS.WORKID != -1
```

Comment: Just use OR instead of AND, I guess

Comment: See apomene's comment. A or B or C returns true _if one or more conditions are true_. This is the basis for programming.

Comment: @user7432713 You might want to add a bit of sample date and expected results to further illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because you required if one contdition in where clause is true than return all the rows so only one option is there you wat to use the OR instead of AND... So 
Try this :

```
SELECT W*.
FROM WORK W JOIN WORKSHOP WS ON W.ID = WS.WORKID
WHERE W.COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL
 OR (W.COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL AND W.COLUMN2 != -1)
 OR  WS.WORKID != -1
```

Comment: OK, basically is what @apomene said in his comment.

Comment: ya if this answer is not helpful to this question then i will delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps simplify it.

```
SELECT W.*
FROM WORK W 
JOIN WORKSHOP WS ON W.ID = WS.WORKID
WHERE (W.COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL OR W.COLUMN2 != -1 OR W.ID != -1)
```

Or inverse the positive.

```
SELECT W.*
FROM WORK W 
JOIN WORKSHOP WS ON W.ID = WS.WORKID
WHERE NOT (W.COLUMN1 IS NULL AND W.COLUMN2 = -1 AND W.ID = -1)
```

Note that `WHERE W.COLUMN2 != -1` wouldn't select the `W.COLUMN2` that are NULL.
So `WHERE (W.COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL AND W.COLUMN2 != -1)` returns the same as `WHERE W.COLUMN2 != -1`